# Java read a file and split lines into array for Output

Tags: java, input, split, output

I have a text file that looks like this

```
 respondentid |              name              |        email        | password | michid 
-------------+--------------------------------+---------------------+----------+--------
 bi1004       | Malapa          Bushra         | bi@tmich.edu  | ec59260f |       
 bm1252       | Peter Benjamin T               | bm@tmich.edu  | 266bff7c |       
 dg1988       | Goday   Priya                  | dg@tmich.edu  | dongara  |
```

I only have to print out only email and name.. but name is reverse order including middle initial.. how do i deal with reverse order and middle initial? for example my printout will be

```
bi@mich.edu  Bushra Malapa
bm@mich.edu  Benjamin T Peter
```

im thinking ill use the split function and also read into arrays. what do yall think? anyone got experience in this? thank you.

Comment: _"im thinking ill use the split function..."_ do it and if you have any problem, then you may ask here

Comment: I think the easiest way is to read the whole line at a time, then split it by `|` into fields and additionally split name field by space.

Comment: Judging from the limited amount of code you gave us, it seems that you're storing passwords in a file, which is a bad idea indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do: I would skip to the 3rd line and then use the split function to split  line at each "|" and store the second and third values as name and email. Then we take the name, split it every time there are any amount of spaces, and rearrange it based on how many parts there are, either First Middle Last or First Last. Then we print it side by side with the email.

Soooooooo here's what that looks like:

```
import java.io.*;
public class temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // define the path to your text file
        String myFilePath = "temp.txt";

        // read and parse the file
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(myFilePath)));
            String line, name, email;
            // read through the first two lines to get to the data
            line = br.readLine();
            line = br.readLine();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (line.contains("|")) {
                    // do line by line parsing here
                    line = line.trim();
                    // split the line
                    String[] parts = line.split("[|]");
                    // parse out the name and email
                    name = parts[1].trim();
                    email = parts[2].trim();
                    // rearrange the name
                    String[] nParts = name.split("  *");
                    if (nParts.length == 3) {
                        name = nParts[1] + " " + nParts[2] + " " + nParts[0];
                    } else {
                        name = nParts[1] + " " + nParts[0];
                    }
                    // all done now, let's print the name and email
                    System.out.println(email + " " + name);
                }
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("There was an issue parsing the file.");
        }
    }
}
```

And if we go ahead and run this with the sample file you provided here's what we get:

> bi@tmich.edu Bushra Malapa
>   bm@tmich.edu Benjamin T Peter
>   dg@tmich.edu Priya Goday

Hope this was helpful to you! I definitely encourage you to find your own way to do this too, because there are plenty of different ways to solve problems and it's good to find a way that makes sense for you. Also as was pointed out you definitely shouldn't store passwords in plain text.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking for advice ...

> im thinking ill use the split function and also read into arrays. what do yall think?

Using the split function to separate the line into fields is one possibility.  Another is to use Scanner.  The split function can also be used to split the name into parts.

Reading stuff into arrays is a bad idea, because you need to know how big the array needs to be beforehand ... and generally speaking there's no way of knowing that.  Use a `List` instead.

---

@GreySwordz has a valid point.  It is **bad practice** for a **real** application to store passwords in clear in a file.  But I suspect this is an exercise ... and the file format has been specified as part of that.